# Disable dates for a selected range in React SharePoint SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience, react

I am new to React SharePoint Online SPFx and want to know how to disable dates in selected range in react-datetime. For now, I am using `npm-reactdatetime` and able to disable dates from current date.

Like if a person is ill in the calendar for like "30th Oct, 2020", he should not be able to select date from 30th Oct to Nov 14, 2020.

Comment: What is the condition to disable the dates? do you want to disable the next 15 days based on current date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about all of your requirements. But, Blocking some dates to be selected is possible while using `react-datetime`.

> It is possible to disable dates in the calendar if the user are not allowed to select them, e.g. dates in the past. This is done using the prop `isValidDate`, which admits a function in the form `function(currentDate, selectedDate)` where both arguments are [moment objects](http://momentjs.com/). The function shall return true for selectable dates, and false for disabled ones.

All you have to do is pass the `isValidDate` prop to react component, call function in this prop, write your business logic in function, and return `true` if you want to allow to select the date or `false` if you want to disable the date.

---

**Example**:

You can use below code to **disable the weekends**:

```
var valid = function( current ){
    return current.day() !== 0 && current.day() !== 6;
};
```

Use react component like:

```
<Datetime isValidDate={ valid } />
```

---

**Reference**: [Blocking some dates to be selected](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datetime#blocking-some-dates-to-be-selected)

Comment: Thanks for the help. It sure helped me a lot and helped also in blocking specific dates